# Passport.js + Express + Next.js + Mongoose -> local authentication does not work

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, passport.js, next.js

I have build a React app using next.js and express for the server. Now I have tried to add local authentication, but the authentication fails every time. I assume it has something to do with not passing in the parameters to the Strategy correctly but I cant figure it out.

I have tried logging the error but passport.js does not return any meaningful errormessage.

**Expected Behavior:**

Users are stored in MongoDB. A user should be able to log in through a login form and then the session for that use should be persisted in a cookie.

**Current Behavior**

After sending the POST to /login the page redirects to /404 as specified in the authenticate method. When adding logging it seems it cant access the user at all.

**server.js**

```
/// BUNCH OF IMPORTS ///

const initializePassport = require("./passportConfig");

const usersApi = require("./api/handlers/usersApiHandlers");

initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => usersApi.getUserBySearchparam(email),
  id => usersApi.getUserBySearchparam(id)
);

const sessionConfig = {
  secret: uid.sync(18),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 86400 * 1000 // 24 hours in milliseconds
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
};

...

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.use(session(sessionConfig));
  server.use(flash());
  server.use(passport.initialize());

  mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on("error", error => console.error(error));
  db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to database"));

  server.use(cors());

  server.post(
    "/login/",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
      successRedirect: "/api/swagger-doc",
      failureRedirect: "/404",
      failureFlash: true
    })
  );

/// Bunch of routes to the different Pages ///
```

**passportConfig.js**

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email);

    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "No user with that email" });
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" });
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error);
    }
  };

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticateUser));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, getUserById(user.id));
  });
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

**getUserBySearchparam**

```
const getUserBySearchparam = searchParam => {
  return fetch(baseURL + searchParam)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
};
```

**returned JSON for getUserBySearchparam**

```
{
    "email": "...",
    "isActivated": true,
    "imageUrl": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "role": "...",
    "_id": "..."
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any of your own efforts to solve the issue, and this is kind of a huge chunk of code for just saying "it's not working." You might get better answer if you cut down the code a bit and explain what you're doing/what you've tried?

Comment: Cut it down further and tried to explain it more. 

The problem I have is that I do not understand what influences the error as it is not working at all and I cant isolate what makes it not work. 

Passport only returns that the authentication failed. I am not sure if that is because I am not passing the parameters correctly from the API/DB or if there is a more fundamental error in the code. 

Already tried to change the way parameters are passed to the strategy.